# STS 3.6 RELEASE error running server

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat7, spring-tool-suite

When I run my project, I don't have errors.
But After login, when I try to enter in a form page the application give me the follow error:

```
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
        java.util.NoSuchElementException
            at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.getJspAttribute(Validator.java:1381)
            at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:772)
            at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$UninterpretedTag.accept(Node.java:1251)
            at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2375)
            at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2427)
            at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:779)
            at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$UninterpretedTag.accept(Node.java:1251)
            at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2375)
            at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2427)
            at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:895)
    ...
```

I think the problem is in the configuration of tomcat but I don't understand where.
I have tomcat7.0.52, use java version 1.7.0_60, idem for jdk.

At my colleague work all without problems, we have the same tomcat version, the only difference is that I have STS 3.6 RELEASE, and He have the 3.5.

**EDIT:**
I try to delete server, and recreate it, but the problem don't change.
I think that the problem is on wrong configuration server because any project I run give me the same error.

This is my catalina arguments:

```
    -Dcatalina.base="/home/paola/Documenti/sts-bundle/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.6.RELEASE/base-instance" 
-Dcatalina.home="/home/paola/Documenti/sts-bundle/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.6.RELEASE/tomcat-7.0.53.B.RELEASE" 
-Dwtp.deploy="/home/paola/Documenti/sts-bundle/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.6.RELEASE/base-instance/wtpwebapps" 
-Djava.endorsed.dirs="/home/paola/Documenti/sts-bundle/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.6.RELEASE/tomcat-7.0.53.B.RELEASE/endorsed" -Xmx768m -Xss256k -XX:MaxPermSize=256m 
-Dinsight.enabled=false -Dspring.profiles.active=dev
```

Any ideas?
Thank

Comment: I am not sure whether this is related to STS 3.6.0 vs. 3.5.0 or to the tc Server version that you are using. Can you configure the older version of tc Server that comes with STS 3.5.0 (the version that your colleagues are using) to see if the problem is within STS or tc Server?

Comment: Resolved. Yesterday I had copy a corrupted version of my colleagues server, now I try again and it's run! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Glad to hear it is working again!!!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is with the version of Tomcat that tcServer is derived from.

[This bug](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56529) which is fixed in Tomcat 7.0.55 is looks like the cause.

I've done some testing and found that the bug is not present in Tomcat 7.0.50, which is used by tcServer Dev Edition 2.9.5.SR1.

So it's either 7.0.51 or 7.0.52 (as you discovered) which introduced the bug.